# Issue with moving items between listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 2 listboxes in my Windows C# WinForms application.  I have written the code to move items between my 2 listboxes.   I can select any/multiple items and move them between the boxes.  However if I select the bottom item in the listbox and move it to the other listbox, then the content in the table it was moved from shows up incorrectly.   Instead of showing the actual contents, it's showing:-  ProgramName__.objectname   for each entry that was above the entry i moved!   This only happens with the last item in the listbox.   If i select the entry that shows up wrong and move it to the other listbox, the correct information shows up.

This appears to me to be a bug, but I'm not sure.  I can move any other item in the listbox and both listboxes show up properly.

```
public class customers
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name {get; set; }
}    



this.table1Box.DataSource = this.customersBindingSource;
this.table1Box.DisplayMember = "name";
this.table1Box.Name = "Table1Name";
this.table1Box.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
this.table1Box.Sorted = true;
this.table1Box.TabIndex = 13;
this.table1Box.ValueMember = "id";

this.table2Box.DataSource = this.customersBindingSource;
this.table2Box.DisplayMember = "name";
this.table2Box.Name = "Table2Name";
this.table2Box.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
this.table2Box.Sorted = true;
this.table2Box.TabIndex = 14;
this.table2Box.ValueMember = "id";


// Click method for moving table 1 -> table 2
private void table1ToTable2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int i in this.table1Box.SelectedIndices)
    {
        selectedCustomer = (customers)this.table1Box.Items[i];

        table2List.Add(selectedCustomer);     
        table1List.Remove(selectedCustomer);

    }
    this.table1Box.DataSource = this.emptyList;
    this.table1Box.DataSource = this.table1List;
    this.table1Box.Update();
    this.table2Box.DataSource = this.emptyList;
    this.table2Box.DataSource = this.table2List;
    this.table2Box.Update();
}
```

![Picture at Start of program] http://www.mclenaghan.com/Pic1.jpg

![Picture after moving last item] http://www.mclenaghan.com/Pic2.jpg

![Picture moving item 2] http://www.mclenaghan.com/Pic3.jpg

Comment: Are you sure this is `WPF`? looks like it's Winforms. I'm going to re-tag it after a few minutes.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Windows Forms.  Duh.

Comment: I did do an interesting test.   After the remove if I do the following:-    table1List = table1List.ToList();   The issue goes away.  However that's a hack, since you're basically copying the whole list of objects to itself.   Since that fixes the issue, I'm wondering if it's a bug, maybe removing the last item is corrupting the list structure somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are binding to `BindingList<customers>`.

You don't need to set the `DataSource` to an empty list and then set to the actual list again and then call `ListBox.Update()`. This seems to be working but it also means you are doing wrong in your binding.

One more thing- Do not edit the designer-generated code by hand, use the Properties Pane. I find even if I change the code sequence in the `InitializeComponent` method, the listbox can display incorrectly.

```
BindingList<customers> table1List;
BindingList<customers> table2List;

public FormWith2Listboxes()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    table1List = new BindingList<customers>();
    table1List.Add(new customers() { id = 1, name = "name1" });
    table1List.Add(new customers() { id = 2, name = "name2" });
    table1List.Add(new customers() { id = 3, name = "name3" });

    table2List = new BindingList<customers>();
    table2List.Add(new customers() { id = 4, name = "name4" });

    this.table1Box.DataSource = this.table1List;
    this.table2Box.DataSource = this.table2List;
}

private void table1ToTable2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int i in this.table1Box.SelectedIndices)
    {
        var selectedCustomer = (customers)this.table1Box.Items[i];

        table2List.Add(selectedCustomer);
        table1List.Remove(selectedCustomer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.    This is my first C# application, so I'm still learning things.